# Child to parent generic convertion in c#

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

I have my base interface class:

```
 public interface IAlgorithm<T> where T : IParams
 {
        /// <summary>
        /// Contains algorythm parameters
        /// </summary>
        T Params{ get; set; }
 }
```

And

```
public interface IParams
{
}
```

Then I have my basic class for algorithm implementation:

```
public abstract class BaseAlgorithm<T> : IAlgorithm<T> where T: IParams
{
    public virtual T Params { get; set; }
}

 public class DataAlgorithm : BaseAlgorithm<IDataParams>
 {
        public override IDataParams Params { get; set; }
 }
```

And params:

```
public interface IDataParams : IParams
{
}
```

There are multiple of `BaseAlgorithm` class implementations.

Now I want to create new isntance of `DataAlgorith` and assign it to the parent interface:

```
IAlgorithm<IParams> algorithm = new DataAlgorithm();
```

but it wont work and produces error message:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'DataAlgorithm' to 'IAlgorithm<IParams>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

The code below will work just fine:

```
IAlgorithm<IDataParams> algorithm = new DataAlgorithm();
```

Any ideas how to assign to parent type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this, because a `DataAlgorithm` is an `IAlgorithm<IDataParams>`, but not an `IAlgorithm<IParams>`.

Think about it. If it was, you would be able to do

```
IAlgorithm<IParams> algorithm = new DataAlgorithm();

algorithm.Params = ... some other kind of IParams but not IDataParams.
```

Obviously, that would make no sense.

If an object is an `IAlgorithm<IParams>`, that means you can assign any object that implements `IParams` to its `Params` property. That is not the case for an object that implements `IAlgorithm<IDataParams>` as that only accepts implementations of `IDataParams` in the `Params` setter. So an `IAlgorithm<IDataParams>` is not an `IAlgorithm<IParams>`.

However, if the setter on the Params property is not required, you can make the interface covariant.

```
public interface IAlgorithm<out T> where T : IParams
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains algorythm parameters
    /// </summary>
    T Params{ get; }
}
```

Adjust your base class accordingly.

Comment: But technically `DataAlgorithm ` is IAlgorithm<IParams>, because DataAlgorithm is IAlgorithm and IDataParams are IParams.

I mean, I would expect it to work in this way. Thanks for sample, I will try.

Comment: @makambi No it is not. That is what I try to explain in the first half of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Kris's answer above, [check out the article on covariance and contravariance on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx).

To make it simple, rather than an `IAlgorithm<IDataParams>`, imagine a `List<IParams>`. Any type implementing `IParams` should be able to be stored in that list. However, imagine the following code:

```
    List<IParams> lst = new List<IDataParams>();
    lst.Add(new ClassImplementingIParamButNotIDataParams());
```

As `List<IDataParams>` only accepts `IDataParams`, the latter statement would be invalid. However, `List<IDataParams> lst = new List<IParams>();` *is* valid: all `IDataParams` that could be added to the list will also be `IParams`.

This is just an example; as Kris said, you can control the covariance/contravariance of a type parameter with the `in` and `out` keywords on your generic. The MSDN article is a good start.

Comment: `List<IDataParams> lst = new List<IParams>();` is not valid! `List<T>` is not contravariant. Only interfaces can be covariant or contravariant, classes cannot. The reason that this is invalid is simple: what is the type of `lst.First()` ? Since lst is a variable of type `List<IDataParams>`, it would have to be something that implements `IDataParams`. But if a `new List<IParams>()` is assigned to `lst`, that cannot be guaranteed. Just to be very complete: a `List<T>` can be assigned to a variable of type `List<U>` if and only if T == U.